# Expect automating login to second level remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I need to login to one development server to put things on live server. 
So processor is like this

- Login to development server.
- Fire Deploy Script
- Deploy script asks for 3 password.
- Followed by ssh pass-phrase password.

I don't have any other access on development and live server. So I can't used key-based authentication. as well as I can't install anything on the server.

Is it possible using expect or any other utility by using that I can automate this ?

I tried using like

```
spawn ssh deploy
expect_after eof { exit 0 }
expect "# "
send "deploy_to_server <branch_name>\r"
expect eof
expect "*password*"  { send "passworrd" }
```

**Edit**

```
   spawn ssh deploy
    send "deploy_to_server <branch_name>\r"
    expect eof
    expect "*password*"  { send "passworrd\n" }
```

Comment: you need to send `\r` not `\n`. `\r` corresponds to the enter key.

Comment: when developing an expect script, always put `exp_internal 1` at the top. You will be able to see why your patterns fail to match.

Comment: @glenn jackman
according to debug info line   expect "*password*"  { send "passworrd\n" } is not waiting for password and sending the output

Comment: Try `expect -re {password: ?$} {send "passworrd\r"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a line terminator in your send:

```
expect "*password*"  { send "passworrd\n" }
```

Apart from that, it seems quite nonsensical to expect eof first and then, without a respawn, wait for a password prompt.

Comment: it is waiting at [sudo] password for deployuser:

Comment: got the issue timeout was happening on expect

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how do you login to development server and how does deploy script work. If everything is text based then it is not a problem to do it using expect script.

Comment: everything is text based.my script hangs at sudo password promt